# Access to ViewController outlets from AppDelegate

Tags: swift, cocoa

I created an outlet in `ViewController` class and I'd like to modify it. 
In the `ViewController.swift` file I have

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
   @IBOutlet var LabelText: NSTextFieldCell?

    override func viewDidLoad() {        
       super.viewDidLoad()
    }
//other things
}
```

I'd like to change the background color of the label. How can I do that from AppDelegate?

At first I thought I could solve this problem using a function in `ViewController` and calling it in `AppDelegate`

```
func changeBackground() {
    LabelText.textColor = NSColor.red
}
```

But soon I realised that it wasn't possible unless I used a static function. Then I tried to modify the code in `ViewController` like that

```
static func changeBackground() {
    LabelText.textColor = NSColor.red
}
```

and call this function in `AppDelegate` like that

```
ViewController.changeBackground()
```

In this way I can access to `changeBackground()` function from `AppDelegate`, but in `ViewController` it gives me an error: `Instance member 'LabelText' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'`

I understood that this cannot be possible because somehow I'm calling "LabelText" before it's initialised (or something like that). 
I don't know much about Swift and I'm trying to understand how it works. I've been searching for the answer to my question for hours, but still I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: just add your code to modify the color in the viewdidLoad of your view controller, and other observation is the name of your element have to start to lowercase letter.

Comment: yeah but then how do I call it in AppDelegate?

Comment: you don't have to use the AppDelegate, for change color and you must no, but in case you want to create new Viewcontroller using different color you just need to add one property called color and setup the value from your appDelegate this color and in your viewdidLoad setup this color to your label.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. But what if I wanted to change the color programmatically? In AppDelegate I've got a function that detect whenever a menu-bar button (those near the wifi icon for example) is triggered. I would like to change the color of the text to a different one when this button is pressed.

Comment: The app delegate should not be reaching into a view controller to perform some function. Standard solution would be to post a custom event in the `NotificationCenter` for which the view controller could add an observer.

Comment: @Rob Ok, I'll try this way. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

As Rob suggested, the solution is to use NotificationCenter.
A useful link to understand how it works: https://www.appypie.com/notification-center-how-to-swift

Anyway, here how I modified the code.
In `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

   @IBOutlet var label: NSTextFieldCell!

   let didReceiveData = Notification.Name("didReceiveData")

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onDidReceiveData(_:)), name: didReceiveData, object: nil)
      super.viewDidLoad()
   }

   @objc func onDidReceiveData(_ notification: Notification) {
      label.textColor = NSColor.red
   }
}
```

And then, in `AppDelegate`:

```
let didReceiveData = Notification.Name("didReceiveData")
NotificationCenter.default.post(name:   didReceiveData, object: nil)
```